# Mark test as passed in Zalenium Dashboard

Tags: selenium, zalenium

I am recoding Selenium Tests with SeleniumIDE, store them as side file and run them with selenium-side-runner on zalenium instance.

Zalenium provides a way to show passed tests
[image]

Under https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/ they state

> Marking the test as passed or failed
>
> By default, tests in Zalenium are marked in the dashboard either as COMPLETED (session finishes normally) or TIMEOUT (session was ended due to inactivity). You can mark the test as passed or failed based on the assertions you do on your side with your test framework, add a cookie from with the name zaleniumTestPassed with a value of true (if the test passes) or false (if the test fails). This could be done in the after method where you already know if the test passed or failed. Here is an example in Java:
>
> ```
> Cookie cookie = new Cookie("zaleniumTestPassed", "true");
> webDriver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
> ```

But how do I do this in Selenium IDE?

I tried

```
 run script  | document.cookie = 'zaleniumTestPassed=true';
```

At the end of the test in the ".side" file but the test is still shown as "completed", but not as "success".

Comment: I have [found a resolution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62712675/how-to-add-cookie-to-selenium-ide-test-running-in-grid-via-selenium-side-runner/62726427#62726427)