# How to add cookie to Selenium IDE test running in grid via selenium-side-runner for Zalenium messages

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-grid2, zalenium, selenium-side-runner

I've recorded a test using `Selenium IDE` and am submitting the generated `.side` file to `selenium-side-runner` to run on a `Selenium Grid` built using `Zalenium`.  Is it possible to run a command that calls `driver.manage().addCookie()` from the test that was submitted to `selenium-side-runner`? I want to do this to send messages back to Zalenium with test progress and status

I added a command `executeScript` to the Selenium IDE editor with a target of `driver.manage().addCookie({name: 'test', value: 'test'})`

I see that the command that selenium-side-runner generated in `commons.js` was

`` await driver.executeScript(`driver.manage().addCookie({name:'test', value: 'test'});`); ``

Doing this causes the browser to report an error `JavascriptError: javascript error: driver is not defined`

I think what I need is the code to be generated without the driver.executeScript wrapper. Is there a way to accomplish this without exporting my `Selenium IDE` test to `NUnit`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this functionality work by crudely modifying the `selenium-side-runner` package on my Windows dev machine

In file `~\node_modules\selenium-side-runner\node_modules\selianize\dist\selianize.cjs.js`

Change

```
function generateScript(script, isExpression = false) {
  return `await driver.executeScript(\`${isExpression ? `return (${script.script})` : script.script}\`${script.argv.length ? ',' : ''}${script.argv.map(n => `vars["${n}"]`).join(',')});`;
}
```

to

```
function generateScript(script, isExpression = false) {
  if (script.script.indexOf('zalenium') > -1)
  {
    return script.script;
  } else 
  {
    return `await driver.executeScript(\`${isExpression ? `return (${script.script})` : script.script}\`${script.argv.length ? ',' : ''}${script.argv.map(n => `vars["${n}"]`).join(',')});`;
  }
}
```

Now when running a test with selenium-side-runner, calling "executeScript" with any value that contains `zalenium` will generate the command verbatim in the test script